# Were AT-AT Walkers in "Star Wars: Rebels" original ones?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

*AT-AT Walkers* are surely tough guys as seen in the movies, especially in Battle of Hoth.

In S01E01 (Droids in Distress) of *Star Wars: Rebels* TV series,

> a small group of stupid jerks (plus, R2-D2 and C3P0) successfully destroyed two AT-AT Walkers within few minutes.

Were those Walkers original ones appeared in the movie or small versions or early prototype?

Initially, I thought they were small versions. But, then I noticed that the weapons used on Walkers were some kind of illegal weapons (T7 Ion Disruptors) capable of disabling Star Destroyers. So, it's possible that those Walkers were original ones.

Can you deduce whether they were original ones or not?

Comment: "original ones"? You mean some sort of early prototypes?

Comment: @phantom42 Why couldn't they be out of beta before that time... unless you have got its release date...

Comment: as an answer already says: AT-DP it is not an AT-AT.  Even though original for rebels they are clearly based on AT-ST not the AT-AT and are thus WAY smaller than AT-ATs. As depicted in a few shots in the series they seem to be only slightly larger or about the same size as a "normal" ground troop transport

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The walkers shown in the show were AT-DPs:

[image: AT-DP walker]

These have only appeared in Rebels, and don't show up in the movies at all.

Source: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Defense_Pod/Canon

Comment: +1 And in addition, AT-DPs are clearly based on AT-STs, not AT-ATs. And true to their AT-ST heritage, they are easily disposed. I mean, *Ewoks* could destroy AT-STs, after all...